# How to customize alert view message of "Cannot Send Tweet"?

Tags: ios, twitter

Using TWTweetComposeViewController (I know, it's deprecated), if a tweet can't be sent for whatever reason, an alert view pops up with title "Cannot Send Tweet", and a message.  Is there a way to customize the message the alert view displays?

Comment: Oh, boy. you are gonna have to post some code. Specifically where the UIAlertView is created and shown.

Comment: Well the alert view is shown by the TWTweetComposeViewController class as far as I can tell.  I can't find anywhere in the code that shows an alert view (I didn't write the code).  It's the default alert that comes up whenever you try to send a tweet and it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight up, public API - there is no such thing as you required.
A bit of ingenuity, and you have a solution. Alert views are displayed inside their own `UIWindow`s. Whenever an alert view is displayed, a new `UIWindow` object becomes visible. When windows become visible, `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` notifications are fired. You could register for this notification and change the alert view's `message`. You will still need to decide whether the current alert view is shown by you or twitter API or someone else.